# NullReferenceException when trying to use a foreach on an Interface

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-game-engine

Here is my C# code within Unity 3D:

```
private List<IEnemy> Enemies;

void Start () {
    soldier = OT.AnimatingSprite("PlayerAnimatingSprite");

    Bomber bomber = new Bomber(soldier);
    Enemies.Add(bomber as IEnemy);
}

void Update () {        
    ProcessEnemies();       
}

void ProcessEnemies()
{
    foreach(IEnemy enemy in Enemies)
    {
        enemy.Move();
    }
}
```

I am also receiving the following warning when I instantiate Bomber in the above code:
"You are trying to create a MonoBehavior using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed. MonoBehaviors can only be added using AddComponent()."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enemies object hasn't been initialised

```
private List<IEnemy> Enemies = new List<IEnemy>();
```

Comment: You need it in this case as IEnemy seems to be an interface. If it as a native type or a class marked as `Serializable` Unity (or Mono/.Net?) does this for you.

Answer (score 3):

AnteSim's answer addresses one problem but the actual error you got comes from trying to call 'new' on Bmber which I assume to be either a GameObject or MonoBehaviour component.

If Bomber is a component:

```
Bomber b = gameObject.AddComponent<Bomber>();
Enemies.Add(b);
```

If Bomber is a GameObject:

```
GameObject b = Instantiate(Bomber, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
Enemies.Add(b);
```

Comment: "as Bomber" is redundant if you're using the generic form of GetComponent.  AddComponent is also not a method of Component like GetComponent is.

Comment: Ack, always forget the gameObject on AddComponent.